# ZF2 JSON array gives a extra not added key back

Tags: arrays, json, zend-framework2, key-value

In my application I created a autocomplete on the search input. When I return the data from my database it's adding a extra key to the array I did not added named '"searchForm":{}'.

Because of this extra key I get an empty `<li>` in my autocomplete menu

My action:

```
 public function autocompleteAction()
    {
        $term     = $this->params()->fromQuery('term');     
        $results  = $this->getWebsiteTable()->searchSites($term, 6);

        foreach ($results as $website)
        {
            $data[] = array('label' => $website->hostname);
        }

        $json = new JsonModel($data);
        return $json;
    }
```

JSON Output:

```
{
    "0": {
        "label": "tumblr.com"
    },
    "1": {
        "label": "tumbleweedtreasures.etsy.com"
    },
    "2": {
        "label": "tumblrenchantment.googlecode.com"
    },
    "3": {
        "label": "tumblring.net"
    },
    "4": {
        "label": "tumbleweedhouses.com"
    },
    "5": {
        "label": "tumblebooks.com"
    },
    "searchForm": {}
}
```

Where is this `searchForm` key coming from? And how do I delete it?

Answer (score 0):

Because of setting a static search form in the application module it tried probably to include this searchForm in the ajax module aswel. Removed the searchForm from the application module and set it in the specific module where it's needed.